# I need to turn this powershell code into C#, because I cant set execution policy to run powershell scripts

Tags: c#, powershell, turn

I work on a computer where I have no admin rights and I am unable to set execution policy. I need to turn this powershell code into C#, so I can make binary module, because those are unaffected by execution policy.

```
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'Red'
$Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = 'Magenta'
$Host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor = 'Black'
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = 'Blue'
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor = 'White'

$Host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = 'DarkYellow'
$Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = 'DarkYellow'
$Host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor = 'DarkYellow'
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor = 'DarkYellow'
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor = 'DarkBlue'

Set-PSReadlineOption -Colors @{
  Command = 'DarkRed';
  Comment = 'DarkGray';
  ContinuationPrompt = 'DarkCyan';
  DefaultToken = 'DarkMagenta';
  Emphasis = 'Red';
  Error = 'DarkRed';
  Keyword = 'DarkGreen';
  Member = 'DarkGreen';
  Number = 'DarkGreen';
  Operator = 'Black';
  Parameter = 'DarkCyan';
  String = 'DarkBlue';
  Type = 'DarkBlue';
  Variable = 'DarkGreen';
}

Set-Location C:\
Clear-Host
```

So I can compile this as .dll with Add-Type cmdlet and use command Load-Colors to execute this module's contents.

Is it possible to make binary profile like Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.dll ?
I have eyesight problems (Astigmatism), I need light colorscheme.
Thank you in advance! Much appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need admin rights to override the execution policy? `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass`

Comment: When I set the White background and Black text in the settings, it does not change the colors of commands. Commands in yellow (Get-Help) became unreadable and others are hard to read. I need to use a custom profile with the code I provided to set colors thru Set-PSReadlineOption. Profile file cant work until I set execution policy to RemoteSigned, which require admin rights on the computer.

Comment: Is the execution policy that you cannot change set via GPO? In other words: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force` doesn't work?

Comment: This works `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass`.
This works too `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` or `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force` to modify the execution policy on a machine you don't have local admin rights on.

Answers from the comments of Mathias R. Jessen & mklement0